# Jquery Form process by PHP case switch and validate dynamic field

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I use this script:

```
    switch($id) {

                //Username and real name need the same validation, so only need one case block here
                case "titel":
                case "graad":
                case "info":
                case "youtube":
                    //Ensure that they are both at least 6 characters long
                    if (strlen($value) < 6) {
                        //To make it more readable, replace the "-"'s with spaces and make the first character upper case
                        $msg = str_replace("-", " ", ucfirst($id)) . " moet minimaal 6 karakters lang zijn.";
                    }
                    break;
                case "personen":
                case "duur":
                    //Use PHP filter to validate the E-Mail address
                    if (!ctype_digit($value)) {
                        $msg = str_replace("-", " ", ucfirst($id)) . " mag alleen uit cijfers bestaan.";
                    }
                    break;
                default:

                        $msg = "";

                    break;
            }
```

I use a dynamic form field with the name: nodig[] and a field aantal[]. Problem is that the input fields are renderd by id.

How can I get the dynamic fields into the switch?

Website with form: http://www.rolfvandamme.nl/beta/ (click on the orange button).

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Putting your code inside a function...and with a foreach post var you call the function to validate

Answer (score 0):

you can get values from textboxes this way :

```
<input type="text" name="array[]" />
<input type="text" name="array[]" />
<input type="text" name="array[]" />

$textbox_values_array = $_POST['array'];
```